# How to display only Duplicate values with a view

Tags: views, database

**Background**

My site is very large already and its only in its infancy. The content title table has 14000+ values in it. To make sure there are no duplicate values in the table I am creating a view that will display all of the institutions with the same title and the same address. At the current time I am just checking title to keep things simple.

**Problem**

The sizeable amount of data means that to return values is very slow.

**Logic and Code**

I am creating a view with address, type & title in a table with the requirement that the only institutes that come in have the same name.

My thoughts were that on every row I would take the `$row->node_title` and put it into a query against every other value in title like

```
$query= db_query("SELECT node.title 
                  FROM node 
                  WHERE ((node.status = '1') 
                  AND (node.type IN ('institution')) 
                  AND (node.title=".$row->node_title."))")->rowCount();
```

This should return a number, if the number is 1 then i want to exclude it with the following statement

```
if($query == 1){ 
  return true
}
```

**Question**

This is taking so long to calculate I thought there must be a faster way. I'm not even sure if the result from this is returning correctly because I've been waiting so long, Is there a faster way to get a list of all the duplicate values in a table with drupal?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Remove Duplicates](https://www.drupal.org/project/remove_duplicates)

> This module helps the administrator to easily remove duplicate nodes according to one of the node fields.